# How to correctly reference multi-dimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array called "$order" (as printed out by "print_r"):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [products] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
             [data] => Array
             (
                 [attributes] => Array
                 (
                     [ID] => Array
                     (
                         [0] => 57
                     )
                  )
             )
         )
    )
)
```

My question is, how do I reference "57"? I thought it would be something like this:

```
$order->products[0]->data[attributes][ID][0];
```

But this doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$order->products[0]->data['attributes']['ID'][0]
```

Comment: Care to share some light on why my method below and your method works?! I dont understand this at all...

Comment: You're missing quotes. Sometimes they work as strings but can get messed up if ID, for example, happens to be a constant.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some quotes for the array keys. Otherwise it makes PHP think that `attributes` or `ID` is a constant (`define('ID', 'foobar'); echo ID;`).

```
$order->products[0]->data['attributes']['ID'][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. It's like this:
$order->products[0]->data["attributes"]["ID"][0];